# Rails Application and Paperclip: <Error><Code>InvalidTlsVersion</Code><Message>Amazon S3 will stop supporting TLS 1.0 and TLS 1.1 connections

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services, ssl, amazon-s3

I have a production application that runs Rails 2.3.2 and Ruby 1.8.7.
*We are in progress of upgrading it to modern versions, but unfortunately haven't finished the upgrade yet.*

The application uses the Paperclip gem to interact with images in an S3 bucket.  Due to AWS no longer supporting TLS 1.0 and 1.1 we have started getting this error when we try to upload images:

```
##### RightAws::S3Interface returned an error: 403 Forbidden
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Error><Code>InvalidTlsVersion</Code><Message>Amazon S3 will stop supporting TLS 1.0 and TLS 1.1 connections. Please update your client to use TLS version 1.2 or above. To learn more and to update your client, see https://go.aws/3AUlVSb . For further assista$
##### RightAws::S3Interface request: https://bucketname.s3.amazonaws.com:443/?prefix=images%2Fimages%mnm%2Foriginal.jpg  ####
Closing HTTPS connection to bucketname.s3.amazonaws.com:443, reason: 'RightAws::AWSErrorHandler: code: 403: 'Forbidden''

RightAws::AwsError (InvalidTlsVersion: Amazon S3 will stop supporting TLS 1.0 and TLS 1.1 connections. Please update your client to use TLS version 1.2 or above. To learn more and to update your client, see https://go.aws/3AUlVSb . For further assistance, co$
  /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p371@vires/gems/right_aws-3.0.4/lib/awsbase/right_awsbase.rb:562:in `request_info_impl'
  /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p371@vires/gems/right_aws-3.0.4/lib/s3/right_s3_interface.rb:203:in `request_info'
  /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p371@vires/gems/right_aws-3.0.4/lib/s3/right_s3_interface.rb:362:in `incrementally_list_bucket'
  /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p371@vires/gems/right_aws-3.0.4/lib/s3/right_s3.rb:239:in `keys_and_service'
  /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p371@vires/gems/right_aws-3.0.4/lib/s3/right_s3.rb:225:in `keys'
  /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p371@vires/gems/right_aws-3.0.4/lib/s3/right_s3.rb:266:in `key'
  vendor/plugins/paperclip/lib/paperclip/storage.rb:180:in `exists?'
  vendor/plugins/paperclip/lib/paperclip/attachment.rb:397:in `queue_existing_for_delete'
  vendor/plugins/paperclip/lib/paperclip/attachment.rb:396:in `map'
  vendor/plugins/paperclip/lib/paperclip/attachment.rb:396:in `queue_existing_for_delete'
  vendor/plugins/paperclip/lib/paperclip.rb:338:in `send'...
```

In my search for a solution I came across this tutorial: https://repost.aws/knowledge-center/s3-access-old-tls

I tried to implement it but unfortunately I wasn't able to get it working.  I'm not super familiar with AWS so I may have misconfigured or misunderstood something.

Is there anything I can do to get requests working while the upgrade is completed on my application?